# Actions on Google account linking lost after saving changes to DialogFlow agent

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

We have created a DialogFlow agent linked to an Actions on Google project for a Google Assistant chatbot.  Our chatbot requires users to have a valid user account in our backend system, so we are using the 'Account Linking' feature in the Actions on Google project.  This is working, however I'm finding that every time I make the slightest change to the agent and save changes, the next time I use the simulator or Google Assistant app it tells me my user is no longer linked, and I have to go through the linking process again.  This can't be right - surely users don't have to re-link their accounts every time the project is updated?  I have not yet sent the app for review - I'm still testing it in 'draft'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct! For live deployed AoG apps, users do not have to re-account link their account as their access token is stored in Google servers unless they decide to RESET their app from the Google Assistant directory listing page of that particular AoG app which results in Google discarding the access token for that particular user and AoG app.

During the testing of your app in the simulator, clicking on TEST DRAFT has the same effect as resetting your AoG app which is deleting the previously granted access token for that specific user and AoG app.